# Not Able to Swipe ViewPager after Dragging my finger from Button

Tags: android, button, android-viewpager, swipe

I have create a View Like below:

[`Button]` [`ViewPager`] [`Button]`

```
               <--------------
```

When I Swipe My finger(*as shown by the Arrow* ) From `Button` to `ViewPager` the ViewPager don't

detect Any Event. Whereas When I take up my Finger and Swipe the ViewPager it Detects the Event.

Problem: How do Swipe the `ViewPager` by dragging my finger from Button to ViewPager

Any Answer is Appreciated...Thks

Answer (score 0):

Show the buttons above the view pager then you will get swiping feature when you swipe above the buttons also. For this you need to design these two buttons in the viewpager row xml that you are inflating to PageAdapter.

Comment: Thks ...But Putting the Button into Viewpager will also Swipe the Button too .I want to swipe the ViewPager when I move my finger from Button to ViewPager :)